# Result of order() differs when applied to data.frame vs. data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, data.table, radix-sort

I get different results if I use `order()` in `data.frame` and `data.table`. For example:

```
A <- data.frame(one = c("k"), two = c("3_28","31_60","48_68"))
B <- as.data.table(A)

A[order(A$one,A$two), ]
#   one   two
# 1   k  3_28
# 2   k 31_60
# 3   k 48_68


B[order(B$one, B$two), ]
#    one   two
# 1:   k 31_60
# 2:   k  3_28
# 3:   k 48_68
```

I must admit this was a bit of a nasty shock, as I have assumed equivalent results for `order()` from `data.frame` and `data.table` for many years. I guess there is a lot of code I need to check!

Is there any way to ensure `order()` gives the same results in `data.frame` and `data.table`?

Many apologies if this difference in behavior is already well known, and is just an example of my ignorance.

Comment: Have a look at data.tables `?setorder` "Note that queries like x[order(.)] are optimised internally to use data.table's fast order." so its not using base::order in the data.table (there are references in the help on data.table's ordering)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When used inside of a `data.table` operation, `order(..)` uses `data.table:::forder`. According to the [Introduction to data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) vignette:

> `order()` is internally optimised
>
> - We can use "-" on a `character` columns within the frame of a `data.table` to sort in decreasing order.
> - In addition, `order(...)` within the frame of a `data.table` uses `data.table`'s internal fast radix order `forder()`. This sort provided such a compelling improvement over R's `base::order` that the R project adopted the `data.table` algorithm as its default sort in 2016 for R 3.3.0, see `?sort` and the R Release NEWS.

From [R News, CHANGES IN R 3.3.0, NEW FEATURES:](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/NEWS.3)

> The radix sort algorithm and implementation from data.table
> (`forder`) replaces the previous radix (counting) sort and adds a
> new method for `order()`.  Contributed by Matt Dowle and Arun
> Srinivasan, the new algorithm supports logical, integer (even
> with large values), real, and character vectors.  It outperforms
> all other methods, but there are some caveats (see `?sort`).

The key to see the difference is that `data.table:::forder` uses a "fast radix order". If you look at `?base::order`, though, it has an argument `method=`:

> the method to be used: partial matches are allowed. The default (`"auto"`) implies `"radix"` for numeric vectors, integer vectors, logical vectors and factors with fewer than 2^31 elements. Otherwise, it implies `"shell"`. For details of methods `"shell"`, `"quick"`, and `"radix"`, see the help for `sort`.

Since the second column of your `data.table` is not one of `numeric`, `integer`, `logical`, or `factor`, then `base::order` uses the `"shell"` method for sorting, which produces different results.

However, if we force `base::order` to use `method="radix"`, we get the same result.

```r
order(A$two)
# [1] 1 2 3
order(A$two, method="radix")
# [1] 2 1 3

A[order(A$one, A$two, method = "radix"),]
#   one   two
# 2   k 31_60
# 1   k  3_28
# 3   k 48_68
```

You can affect the same ordering by using `base::order`:

```r
B[base::order(B$one,B$two),]
#       one    two
#    <char> <char>
# 1:      k   3_28
# 2:      k  31_60
# 3:      k  48_68
```

Added note: all `method=` options for `base::order` depend on locale except `method="radix"`, which then mimics `data.table::order` more closely. From `?base::order`:

> Except for method ‘"radix"’, the sort order for character vectors
> will depend on the collating sequence of the locale in use...

Comment: Incredibly helpful thank you, @r2evans. The fact that ```base::order``` uses ```radix``` for lots of data types, but not ```character``` probably explains why I never noticed this discrepancy before. I imagine there is no way to make a ```data.table``` sort using ```shell```?

Comment: Sure ... use `base::order(...)`, and you'll get the shell-ordering. The only consequence is that it won't be highly optimized.